# Why this code below fails

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *top;
int a=1;
top=&a;

void main()
{
    printf("%d\n",*top);
}
```

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'
```

**UPDATE**

I know how to make it work,but I'm asking why it DOESN'T work.

Comment: Unless your implementation defines `main` as returning `void` as an extension to the Standard, you invoke Undefined Behaviour with this program. Anything can happen: be happy the code failed and you got to ask SO about it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually tripping over the compiler's support for ancient C syntax.  The original C compiler allowed declarations without a type, defaulting it to int.  So outside of any function,

```
foo;
```

would declare a global `int` variable called `foo`.  So when you say

```
top = &a;
```

it declares a global int variable called `top` and tries to initialize it with the address of `a`.  This gives you the two errors you see -- two conflicting declarations for `top` and an inability to convert an `int *` to an `int`.  Of course those same ancient C compilers would not give you the second error, happily converting the address to an int without complaint.

This also tells you why `int i; i = 100;` works --- its two declarations for `i` as a global `int` variable (which is ok, as they're the same type), and the second initializes it to `100` (which is ok as only one declaration has an initializer)

There's lots of fascinating stuff in Dennis Ritchie's [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit surprised at the exact error message you got about it, but the problem (or at least one of the obvious problems) is that outside of a function, you're allowed to define and initialize variables, but you're *not* allowed to do a normal assignment -- that has to be done as part of executing a function. As such, your `top=&a;` isn't allowed.

Another problem is that you have `main` returning `void`, where it should return an `int` (though most compilers will accept that without even a warning, not to mention an error message).

Comment: +1, and compilers certainly have some rather oddball errors for this one. `clang` and `gcc` do not give very accurate errors for this problem.

Comment: Why can't `top=&a; ` be regarded as initializing for `top`?

Comment: @justnobody see either mine or Chris Dodd's answers further down for an explanation of why that code works. You are actually declaring a variable named `i` twice, just that the second one has an implicit, default type of `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, from your original code:

```
int *top;
int a=1;
top=&a;
```

As others have mentioned - in global space you can declare, or declare and initialize. You can not do assignment.

What is actually happening in the line `top = &a;` is that you are actually re-declaring a variable called `top`, and it defaults to the `int` type. The compiler should actually warn about creating a new variable named `top` that has the same name as a previously declared variable, as well as generate an additional warning that you are creating a variable of default type `int`.

In C, variables that are declared without a type default to `int`, and that would generate the error you see.

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'

What this is really complaining about is that `top = &a;` as in your code actually looks like `int top = &a;` to the compiler, so you are trying to bind an `int*` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *top;
int a=1;
int main()
{
    top=&a;
    printf("%d\n",*top);
}
```

You need to be sure not do global assignment like that. You can only do initialization, nothing else for global variables.

You also have not mentioned the other errors, please mention all errors, sometimes one error is based of another and when one is fixed the others get fixed. In this case it was:

> Conflicting types for 'top'.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly have no idea why that fails, but this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 1;
int* top = &a;

void main()
{
    printf("%d\n", *top);
}
```

And remember: ALWAYS INITIALIZE YOUR POINTERS!!
If you're not going to assign them immediately, at least do something like this:

```
int* top = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=1;
int *top=&a;

void main()
{
    printf("%d\n",*top);
}
```